# To avoid union for mostly same set of tables

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

I have a query in db2 for which I'm trying to see if there is a way to avoid union here.

```
SELECT T1.A, T2.B ,T3.C 
FROM TABLE_1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 
    ON T1.A = T2.A
INNER JOIN TABLE_3 T3 
    ON T1.A = T3.A
WHERE T1.DATE = DATE_CHECK AND T3.DATE = DATE_CHECK AND T2.DATE = DATE_CHECK_1

UNION

SELECT T1.A, T2.B ,T3.C 
FROM TABLE_1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 
    ON T1.A = T2.A
INNER JOIN TABLE_3 T3 
    ON T1.A = T3.A
INNER JOIN TABLE_4 T4 
    ON T1.A = T4.A
WHERE T1.DATE = DATE_CHECK AND T3.DATE = DATE_CHECK AND T2.DATE = DATE_CHECK_2 AND T4.E = 'VALUE'
```

In the second part , we have TABLE_4 added and few different conditions.
TABLE_2 IS relatively huge.

DATE_CHECK value remains same wherever it is referenced. DATE_CHECK_1 AND DATE_CHECK_2 are different. T2.DATE is used to check with different values in both the queries.

Could someone give idea on how to make it as single query to avoid using huge table twice.

Thanks in advance.

2 queries in the union i optimized, but  missing some point in avoiding union.

Comment: Presumably the second SELECT produces a subset of the dataset produced by the first SELECT - so you have duplicates in your overall resultset? If this is the case, and you want to keep the duplicates then you can't get away from using a UNION. You could make your query easier to read by moving the common parts to a CTE - but that (probably) won't affect what actually gets executed

Comment: you can't get rid of the union, because both select can have different results, else you would have it n the first place and if condition3 is a subset of 4 an5 we can#t even imagine

Comment: Table2 is only used for lookups (since it's outer-joined), not as a driving table. If the lookups can be retrieved using indexes and the cardinality of those lookups is relatively low there shouldn't be a performance hit. How many rows do you expect to retrieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a valid `WHERE` clause.  Be sure to include the table references.  Without that, there is insufficient clarity to provide an accurate solution.

Comment: @NickW Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried CTE for other similar queries. Execution time was bit faster but the query cost didn't come out as expected. But I will give it a try here.

Comment: @nbk yeah, finding it little difficult. Hoping to see if we can sort it out.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah it's a lookup table. Index option let me if that is possible here.. we have restrictions on indexes. Resultset would have couple of millions because of lookup table. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Community i have added couple.of more details.

Comment: @dougp thanks for pointing it out. Have added details. Please let me know if this is okay..

Comment: The WHERE clauses provided are not valid. Please, provide valid ones. Why do you use LEFT JOIN T2? If you use T2.DATE=... in WHERE, then it effectively means INNER JOIN T2.

Comment: Please provide a valid `WHERE` clause.  We need to know how those conditions are processed.  Use `AND`, `OR` and parentheses as needed.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Ah, the classic `LEFT INNER JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @PSK I see comments like "Execution time was a bit faster..." meaning you have working code.  Pasting the working code would be more helpful than making us guess.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.A, T2.B ,T3.C 
FROM TABLE_1 T1
JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.A = T2.A
JOIN TABLE_3 T3 ON T1.A = T3.A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_4 T4 ON T1.A = T4.A
WHERE T1.DATE = DATE_CHECK AND T3.DATE = DATE_CHECK AND 
(
  T2.DATE = DATE_CHECK_1
    OR
  T2.DATE = DATE_CHECK_2 AND T4.E = 'VALUE'
)
```